# Create new SharePoint user using SharePoint Online Management Shell

Tags: powershell, office-365, user

I have a `*.sharepoint.com` tenant provisioned through singing up for Office 365. Is there a way to create a new user for the tenant using PowerShell (for SharePoint Online)?

This would normally be done manually by going to the admin panel and going through the options to create a new user (for O365 and Exchange, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

This is done by the PowerShell Script [New-MsolUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194096) either by adding the user without a license:

```
New-MsolUser 
-UserPrincipalName JWarner@contoso.com 
-DisplayName "Jamie Warner" 
-FirstName "Jamie" 
-LastName "Warner"
```

Or with a license

```
New-MsolUser 
-UserPrincipalName DomTru@contoso.com 
-DisplayName "Dominique Trujillo" 
-FirstName "Dominique" 
-LastName "Trujillo" 
-UsageLocation "US" 
-LicenseAssignment "Contoso:BPOS_Standard"
```

Be sure to install the [Azure AD Module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx#bkmk_installmodule) first

Comment: Link to download the Azure AD module [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx#bkmk_installmodule) (I was typing up an answer myself, then saw that someone already posted one)

Answer (score 1):

First, [Install Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=28177).

Then, Run this Powershell :

```
Connect-MsolService

Get-MsolAccountSku

$val = Get-MsolAccountSku |ForEach-Object {;$_.AccountSkuId;}
$mytnt = $val.Split(":")[0]


New-MsolUser -DisplayName "John Smith" -FirstName "John" -LastName "Smith" -UserPrincipalName john@mytnt.onmicrosoft.com -Department Operations -UsageLocation US -PassWord myPassword -LicenseAssignment $val

echo "User created successfully"

Pause
```